# call one lwc component from another html file not working

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter

I have cmp 1 and cmp 2. In cmp2 i am getting data from apex.

I am calling cmp2 from cmp1's html file like below:

cmp1 : HTML

```
<c-cmp2 prodid={prdid}/>
```

In cmp2 js file i am doing below code:

```
import apexmethod from ...;
@api prodId

  @wire (apexmethod,{prodId:'$prodId'})
        optnProd({error,data}){
            if(data){//do something}
}
```

but this wire apex call is not working. The apex call itself not happening as i am not getting any logs. Can anybody tell me the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of using `<c-cmp2 prodid={prdid}/>`

try it like `<c-cmp2 prodid={prdid}></cmp2>`